# Complex Claim Values in .NET Framework with System.Security.Claims

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, wif, owin, claims-based-identity

I'm developing a web app with Asp.Net 5 MVC, Owin and Oauth2 bearer token as auth type.

Following [this guide](http://www.garycrawford.co.uk/complex-claim-values-with-wif/) that adds a custom complex claim Json serialized to an instance of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` with success, I've tried to replicate the same example using the [ClaimsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the `System.Security.Claims` namespace.

Unluckily, it seems that adding a `complexClaim` to the `ClaimsIdentity` instance, the derived class type information is lost, and the claim is stored as a `System.Security.Claims.Claim`.

```
var complexClaim = new ComplexClaim<UKPassport>(@"http://it.test/currentpassport", passport);
var claims = new List<Claim>() { complexClaim };
identity.AddClaims(claims);
```

When I  try to get back the claim from identity, casting it to to a `ComplexClaim<UKPassport>` Type results in a null value.

```
var passportClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault<Claim>(c=>c.Type == @"http://it.test/currentpassport") as ComplexClaim<UKPassport>;
```

The same example works perfectly using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims`.

Any hints?

Here is the complete ported code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program {
    private static ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var oldPassport = CreatePassport();
        identity.AddPassport(oldPassport);

        var britishCitizen = identity.IsBritishCitizen();
        var hasExpired = identity.IsCurrentPassportExpired();
        Console.WriteLine(hasExpired); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static UKPassport CreatePassport()
    {
        var passport = new UKPassport(
            code: PassportCode.GBR, 
            number: 123456789,
            expiryDate: DateTime.Now);

        return passport;
    }
}

    public static class ClaimsIdentityExtensions {
    public static void AddPassport(this ClaimsIdentity identity, UKPassport passport)
    {
        var complexClaim = new ComplexClaim<UKPassport>(@"http://it.test/currentpassport", passport);

        var claims = new List<Claim>() { complexClaim };
        identity.AddClaims(claims);
    }

    public static bool IsCurrentPassportExpired(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var passport = GetPassport(identity, @"http://it.test/currentpassport");
        return DateTime.Now > passport.ExpiryDate;
    }

    public static bool IsBritishCitizen(this ClaimsIdentity identity)
    {
        var passport = GetPassport(identity, @"http://it.test/currentpassport");
        return passport.Code == PassportCode.GBR;
    }

    private static UKPassport GetPassport(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string passportType)
    {
        var passportClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault<Claim>(c=>c.Type == @"http://it.test/currentpassport") as ComplexClaim<UKPassport>;
        return passportClaim.Value;
    }
}

    public enum PassportCode
    {
        GBR,

        GBD,

        GBO,

        GBS,

        GBP,

        GBN
    }


    public class ComplexClaim<T> : Claim where T : ClaimValue
    {
        public ComplexClaim(string claimType, T claimValue)
            : this(claimType, claimValue, string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public ComplexClaim(string claimType, T claimValue, string issuer)
            : this(claimType, claimValue, issuer, string.Empty)
        {
        }

        public ComplexClaim(string claimType, T claimValue, string issuer, string originalIssuer)
            : base(claimType, claimValue.ToString(), claimValue.ValueType(), issuer, originalIssuer)
        {
        }

        public new T Value
        {
            get
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(base.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class UKPassport : ClaimValue
    {
        public const string Name = "UKPassport";

        private readonly PassportCode code;
        private readonly int number;
        private readonly DateTime expiryDate;

        public UKPassport(PassportCode code, int number, DateTime expiryDate)
        {
            this.code = code;
            this.number = number;
            this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
        }

        public PassportCode Code { get { return this.code; } }
        public int Number { get { return this.number; } }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get { return this.expiryDate; } }

        public override string ValueType()
        {
            return @"http://it.test/currentpassport";
        }
    }    

public abstract class ClaimValue {
    public abstract string ValueType();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not supported nor recommended - claims are key / value pairs - keep them as simple as possible.

There are a number of supporting classes in .NET that can't handle what you are trying to achieve (the SAM, CookieMiddleware etc)..

see also here
http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/08/custom-claims-principals-in-net-4-5/

Comment: I've read a few of your responses and your blog, but I'm still not sure about a scenario described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380623/complex-claims-in-jwt where as part of the user identity we want to have his roles for different businesses. That seems to me part of the info about "who a user is", but it would require a complex JWT that you seem not to like much..

Comment: Does this statement "There are a number of supporting classes in .NET ..." still stand true now with the newer framework versions and/or dotnet core?

Comment: Seems like it. ProbabIy because the Claim gets serialized. If the custom claim overrides the serialization it might work though.

Answer (score 2):

The cast in `GetPassport` tries to convert from base type `Claim`  to derived type `ComplexClaim<UKPassport>` which will result in null.
You need to write a cast operator to convert from `Claim` to `UKPassport`

```
public static explicit operator UKPassport(Claim c)
{
     return (c == null ? null:JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UKPassport> (c.Value));
}
```

and `GetPassport` will be

```
private static UKPassport GetPassport(this ClaimsIdentity identity, string passportType)
{
   return (UKPassport)identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault<Claim>(c => c.Type == @"http://it.test/currentpassport");
}
```